# how to translate quote symbol?

Tags: xslt

I try to `translate(tag, ''', '')`, but it doesn't work.  Is it possible to delete or change symbol ' ?

Best regards.

Comment: one of the answer: <xsl:with-param name="str" select='normalize-space(translate(tag,"&apos;", ""))' />

Comment: If you think yours is a posible answer, then you should post it as answer, not as comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either replace the innermost `'` with `&apos;` or use quotation marks to delimit a string containing an apostrophe.

Comment: XPath [string literal](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-Literal) can't use delimiters in content.

Answer (score 11):

I find it best to use variables for this:

```
<xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="quot">"</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="translate(., $apos, $quot)"/>
```

Comment: Yes _________________________

Answer (score 0):

I want to offer another answer, because the others didn't work when I use this method.
I have solved it in a different way.
You should do as this:

```
<xsl:value-of select='translate(translate(translate(normalize-space(@onclick),"()",""),"&apos;",""),"submitLSthis, product.php?p=","")' />
```

It should be

**select=''**, not select="",

and

translate(translate(translate(normalize-space(@onclick),"()",""),"'",""),"submitLSthis, product.php?p=","")

not

translate(translate(translate(normalize-space(@onclick),'()',''),''',''),'submitLSthis, product.php?p=','')

I hope this is helpful.